# Script Tag Renders Javascript As Text With Seemingly Valid HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script tag that is two levels removed from the html body element. For some reason when this script tag renders, all the text renders instead of being interpreted as JS:

[image: script contains its child]

So, the tag doesn't render properly. The script text is rendered to the screen instead of being recognized as JS code:[image]

The above is my navbar rendering javascript code as text. The html that produces the text is:

```
<span class="account-button" onclick="accountButtonPressed()">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        Sign In
    {% else %}
        Sign Out
    {% endif %}
</span>


<script>function accountButtonPressed(){if(isSignedIn){signUserOut();}else{toggleCreateAccount();}}</script>
```

I can't find this error anywhere else online. I'm wondering if it's an error with chrome or something at this point, since my HTML *seems* perfectly valid. Chrome version 75. All javascript that's coming from my coding is included in the HTML file. The HTML renders in the same incorrect way in the Network Tab response view.

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting what the console is showing you.

Comment: @Pointy I'm not, I just checked again, what I said is exactly what is happening, I can look at other script tags and the tree is rendered differently. If I press the arrow on the script tag, the </script> dissapears as it is a child of the <script> tag. Unless you have another explanation as to why the </script> would dissapear when I hide the <script>'s children, or why chrome would render it that way.

Comment: A `</script>` tag cannot possibly be a child of anything; that's not how HTML or the DOM works. However if a string is being rendered then *something* is going on. What framework is involved? What does the actual HTML look like in the Network tab response view?

Comment: @Pointy You're right my bad, thanks for correcting. I'm not using any front end framework except Jquery, rendering some things server side with Django templating. It's all rendered as a single html file before being sent to the client, there are no separate JS files except for Jquery and such.

Comment: Is the script in a template file?  it's possible the back end is scrubbing the tag chars.   Check if the serving is not converting the < > tags into `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Comment: @briansol that's a thing I considered, but if that were the case then the console would not be showing the script as a tag. OP: is that *exactly* what your code looks like?  The `<script>` tag is "plain" without a "type" or "language" attribute?

Comment: @Pointy Yes that is the entire file copy/pasted. There's an `{% include 'button.html' %}` in a different HTML file it's being rendered into.

Comment: Well something weird must be happening *somewhere*; obviously a plain `<script>` tag in a plain static HTML page would not behave that way. All I can suggest again is to look at what actually ends up being delivered to the browser by checking the HTTP response in the developer tools.

Comment: @Pointy I just checked the response, and the script tag is delivered precisely as it appears above. I've figured it out though, although I'm not sure if this question is worth keeping up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that if you set `display: inline-block` to a `<script>` tag, it renders the script as text. I had set the style inadvertently in CSS.

Comment: Amazing. It would have taken me a long time to guess that :)